# How to change a tensor object from gaussian process library into an numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, gaussian, gaussian-process

I want to convert a tensor object, in this case predicted values obtained by using a gaussian process model, into a numpy array.

I was writing this block of coding that goes as follows.

```
# Predict using the validation set
num_samples = 10
X_val_reshaped = np.ravel(X_val)
samples = gp.sample(X_val_reshaped, num_samples)
samples = tf.reshape(samples, [num_samples, -1, 1])
pred_mean = tf.reduce_mean(samples, axis=0)
pred_var = tf.math.reduce_variance(samples, axis=0)
```

However, I got the samples in a tensor type. I want to convert it into a numpy array so that I can calculate the RMSE value. When I try to write samples.eval() or samples.numpy(), I got error messages, such as Tensor object has no attribute 'numpy' or the other message like, No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess). And also, when I try to write these code lines

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    rmse_val = sess.run(samples)
    print('samples:', samples)
```

it is still not a numpy object. Is there any idea how to convert a tensor object, in this case the predicted values obtained by using a gaussian process model, into a numpy object?

Comment: `tf` has some sort of `to_numpy()` method.  Have  you read the `tf` docs?

Comment: I had tried to_numpy() as well, but it showed the same error message too @hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the tensor to compute the RMSE instead of converting it to a Numpy array.

The formula for RMSE , as you know is :

[image]

The way to implement it in TF is -

```
tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y1, Y2))).
```